# I'm unable to map different url to same controller in spring mvc

Tags: spring

I have already few question in stack but didn't got my sol.

I have different brand list which I want to map to one controller so that all products from respective brands I can retrieve and display them in jsp.

JSP
--------

```
div id="sportswear" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <div class="panel-body">
                     <ul>
                                <li><a href="brands.htm/nokia">Nokia </a></li>
                                <li><a href="brands.htm/apple">Apple </a></li>
                                <li><a href="brands.htm/xaomi">Xaomi </a></li>
                                <li><a href="brands.htm/motorola">Motorola</a></li>
                                <li><a href="brands.htm/samsung">Samsung </a></li>
                    </ul>
 </div>
```

Controller
---------------

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= {"/brands.htm"})
public class ShowBrandsProducts {
    @Autowired
    private ECommerceService service;

    public String getPage() {
        return "shop";
    }

    @RequestMapping(name="/nokia")
    public String getNokia(Model model) {
        List<DisplayFeatureProducts> displayList= null;
        List<FeaturedItemsObject> listFeature= new ArrayList<>();
        ByteToImage big= null;

        try {
            //getting all nokia products
            displayList= service.getProductFromBrand("nokia");
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }

        displayList.forEach(dl->{
            //getting the products from displayList
            FeaturedItemsObject fio= new FeaturedItemsObject();
            fio.setId(dl.getId());
            fio.setName(dl.getName());
            fio.setPrice(dl.getPrice());
            String encoded= big.convertByteToImage(dl.getImage());
            fio.setEncodedImage(encoded);
            //adding the products to listFeature to List 
            listFeature.add(fio);
        });

        model.addAttribute("brand", listFeature);
        return "shop";
    }

}
```

I have got a sol like if I'm placing **@Requestparam( params = {"id=nokia"})**  
 above this method  **public String getNokia(Model model)** and passing the url like **/brands?id=nokia**it's working fine.
But I want to give the request not by id only simple like **/brands.htm/nokia**

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a `@PathVariable`

As linked by JB Nizet, you'll find it in Spring's documentation :

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

It's quite straightforward :

> ```
> @RestController
> @RequestMapping("/persons")
> class PersonController {
>
>     @GetMapping("/{id}")
>     public Person getPerson(@PathVariable Long id) {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

You're looking to do the same with your brands.
For example :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/brands.htm")
class BrandsController {

    @GetMapping("/{brand}")
    public Model getModelFromBrand(@PathVariable String brand) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You may also use an enum instead of a String to better fit your needs.